# How do I find out what version of Linux I'm running?

Tags: linux, command-line, version

Is there a way to determine what version (distribution & kernel version, I suppose) of Linux is running (from the command-line), that works on any Linux system?

Comment: I'd just like to point out for the record how stupid it is that this is a question which needs asking. This is really quite an indictment on the state of every linux distro.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

The kernel is universally detected with `uname`:

```
$ uname -or
2.6.18-128.el5 GNU/Linux
```

There really isn't a cross-distribution way to determine what distribution and version you're on. There have been attempts to make this consistent, but ultimately it varies, unfortunately. LSB tools provide this information, but ironically aren't installed by default everywhere. Example on an Ubuntu 9.04 system with the `lsb-release` package installed:

```
$ lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:        9.04
Codename:       jaunty
```

Otherwise, the closest widely-available method is checking `/etc/something-release` files. These exist on most of the common platforms, and on their derivatives (i.e., Red Hat and CentOS).

Here are some examples.

Ubuntu has `/etc/lsb-release`:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jaunty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 9.04"
```

But Debian has `/etc/debian_version`:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
5.0.2
```

Fedora, Red Hat and CentOS have:

```
Fedora: $ cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 10 (Cambridge)

Red Hat/older CentOS: $ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.3 (Final)

newer CentOS: $ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

Gentoo:

```
$ cat /etc/gentoo-release
Gentoo Base System release 1.12.11.1
```

I don't have a SUSE system available at the moment, but I believe it is `/etc/SuSE-release`.

Slackware has `/etc/slackware-release` and/or `/etc/slackware-version`.

Mandriva has `/etc/mandriva-release`.

For most of the popular distributions then,

```
$ cat /etc/*{release,version}
```

will most often work. Stripped down and barebones "server" installations might not have the 'release' package for the distribution installed.

Additionally, two 3rd party programs you can use to automatically get this information are [Ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html) and [Facter](https://puppetlabs.com/facter).

Note that many distributions have this kind of information in `/etc/issue` or `/etc/motd`, but some security policies and [best practices](http://cisecurity.org) indicate that these files should contain access notification banners.

Related:
[How to find out version of software package installed on the node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22179193/1672723),
[puppet](/questions/tagged/puppet).

Comment: Lol here I was thinking to suggest: look for About!

Comment: Slackware has /etc/slackware-version

Comment: Thanks Ken, I don't have a slackware system either.

Comment: IOW: ls /etc/*{release,version} and examine whatever comes back...

Comment: freiheit, you ought to put that in a separate answer.

Comment: Mandriva has /etc/mandriva-release

Comment: Most also have /etc/issue

Comment: @dinomite Indeed, and many put that information there, but it shouldn't be considered definitive, and is often used for access banners as I had added to the answer earlier.

Comment: SuSE: `cat /etc/SuSE-release` (just tested, it works)

Answer (score 45):

You could also try:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
```

It usually (not always, though) will tell you what distribution you are using. `/etc/issue` is the file used for the login screen.

Comment: This is the only one that nailed it for me on a shared Media Temple server. Thanks!!

Comment: Ha, on RedHat, that's just `\S[newline]Kernel \r on an \m`

Comment: For example for Linux Mint

Answer (score 20):

Kernel: `uname -a`

Comment: +1. For similar systems, like [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), the "-a" is required to get the version information, for example, "MINGW32_NT-5.1 LAP065 1.0.17(0.48/3/2) 2011-04-24 23:39 i686 Msys".

Answer (score 17):

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

at a minimum for Ubuntu, Fedora and OpenSUSE.

Does not work for OS X at least until 10.9 (Mavericks).  Use ***sw_vers*** instead.

OpenSUSE had ***cat /etc/SuSE-release*** up until 13.1 but is deprecated in favour of os-release.

Redhat 6.1 has **cat /etc/redhat-release**

Comment: DOC: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html

Answer (score 14):

`lsb_release -a`, when available, is useful.

Answer (score 13):

`cat /proc/version` found me Red Hat on a shared VPS.

Answer (score 6):

Kernel: `uname -r`

Distro: `lsb_release -a`

These will run on most Linux systems

Answer (score 5):

## One-liner

```
lsb_release -a && uname -r
```

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment on Albert Z's answer.

Comment: mighty answer to conclude all answers! I must upvote for the effort :)

Answer (score 3):

This **issue can also be solved** using **[Python with the `platform` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/platform.html)**:

Using `platform()` function:

```
python3 -c 'import platform; print(platform.platform())'
# Linux-6.1.0-9-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.36
```

The above command *returns a single string identifying the underlying platform with as much useful information as possible.*

Or using `uname()` function:

```
python3 -c 'import platform; print(platform.uname())'
# uname_result(system='Linux', node='debian', release='6.1.0-9-amd64', version='#1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.27-1 (2023-05-08)', machine='x86_64')
```

The above command *returns a `namedtuple()` containing five attributes: `system`, `node`, `release`, `version` and `machine`.*