# How do I know what my Linux Version is on a hosting server?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what version of Linux I’m running?](https://superuser.com/questions/11008/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-im-running)

I need to download the right rebol version here
http://www.rebol.com/view-platforms.html

Is there a ssh command to know which version of Linux the hosting server uses ?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/11008/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-im-running

Answer (score 3):

If you can ssh to it the you can try a command like

```
cat /proc/version
```

hope hat helps

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
uname -a
```

THis will give you a few other details you might like to know too