# How to determine linux version on server

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what version of Linux I'm running?](https://superuser.com/questions/11008/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-im-running)

I purchased a web server recently and have got access to shell on it.  I dont know the linux version on the server. I am not used to running linux commands, so can anybody help me in determining the linux version using the shell commands.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by "linux version".  You can get a lot of information from:

```
$ uname -a
```

If you want specifics about the distribution, it will depend on the distro.  For example:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
```

will give information if you're on a red hat box, but not much if you're on Debian.

You can also try any of:

```
$ cat /proc/version
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
$ cat /etc/issue
$ cat /etc/debian_version
$ cat /etc/*version
$ cat /etc/slackware-version
$ cat /etc/SuSE-release
$ cat /etc/*release
```

I'm sure the list is endless, but /etc/*version or /etc/*release should (probably) do it.

Comment: yes i want to know about the distribution too..thanx a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
uname -a
```

or

```
cat /proc/version
```

Answer (score 3):

Some distros come with lsb_release. 
Try

```
lsb_release -a
```

Answer (score 1):

the uname command should help.  to get all information about a system type :

```
uname -a
```

to get more info about the command you can type:

```
man uname
```

the command `man` is a linux staple and provides documentation about most if not all commands available.

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try [uname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname):

```
f0725470@g0:~$ uname --all
Linux g0 2.6.30-perfctr #1 SMP Wed Sep 16 15:56:16 CEST 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*

Try this command it will show kernal name (-s) , kernel release (-r) and kernel version (-v)

For details do $man uname
*/

$uname -s -r -v
```